# Agroup Number format 2745 to "2.7"k Android

Tags: java, android, numbers

I want to transform numbers, for example: 2745 to "2.7"
I have a double with that number, can be 1 or 10000000.

I want to do that with number up 1000. 
Can I do ?

Comment: Does *number up 1000* mean numbers greater than 1000?

Comment: *"Can I do ?"* Yes

Comment: Yes, I meant greather than 1000.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String rounding(int i) {
    if (i < 1000 && i > -1000) return Integer.toString(i);
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    final DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
    String prefix = "-";
    if (i < 0) i = -i;
    else prefix = "";
    if (i < 1000000) return prefix + df.format((double) i / 1000) + "k";
    else if (i < 1000000000) return prefix + df.format((double) i / 1000000) + "M";
    else return prefix + df.format((double) i / 1000000000) + "G";
}


private static String roundToKilos(int i) {
    if (i < 1000 && i > -1000) return Integer.toString(i);
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    final DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final boolean negative = i < 0;
    if (negative) i = -i;
    int divider = 1000;
    double d = 0;
    while (i / divider >= 1) {
        d = (double) i / divider;
        divider *= 1000;
        sb.append("k");
    }
    sb.insert(0, df.format(d));
    if (negative) sb.insert(0, "-");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: That solution works when number is less than 1.000.000, but for example 2756564 returns : "2.8kk"
How can I fix?

Comment: Does the same. :|

Comment: 187564663 returns 187.5kk

Comment: Really, the result expected is something like that : "187.5M"
When over 1000, "k" and over million "m", but never repeat the letter.
We can do that? Thank you so much, by the way.

Comment: I added another method, not sure if I understood correctly

Comment: Now works! thank you so much, but what is the "G" letter?

Comment: giga? you can change it on any letter or string, e.g. "mom"